# Question about the definition of a supremum

Tags: definition, limsup-and-liminf

I want to know if the next definition is correct or I should fix it:
Lets say that we have set $K$ and $a\in K$.
Then, if $a\sup K$, for every $x\in K\Rightarrow x<a$?

Or I shold cahge it to $x\le a$?

Thank you!

Comment: What does $a$ sup $K$ mean for an element in a group? So you have an ordered group?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, If I'm understand you right - Yes. e.g.: $K=[1,2]$ or $(1,2)$...

Comment: How are those groups?

Comment: At any rate, since $a\in K$ (which makes it a maximum, not just a supremum) you cannot have for all $x\in K$ that $x<a$ - just pick $x=a$, in which case, well, $x=a$

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, $K=[1,2]={x\in K|1\le x \le 2}$, $K=(1,2)={x\in K|1<x<2}$...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, So I need to fix it to "$\le$"??

Comment: I am aware of how intervals are defined. I was asking how those intervals were groups, but it seems that this question is not actually about groups at all.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, they are infinite groups if I'm understanding it right...

Comment: No, they are not groups at all. They are sets, unless you have some exotic operation in mind for them.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, Sorry!! You right!! (Because at Hebrew, the meaning of "group", it's like "set" at math...)

Answer (score 0):

If $a=\sup K$, then for every $x \in K$ it is the case that $x \leq a$ (not $x <a$). To see this, consider $K=[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$, in which case $\sup K = 1 \in K$.